# jinja format strings that could be "None"

Tags: jinja2

I'm getting started with Jinja by converting my Django templates.  Let's say I have a variable that represents a dollar value.  So if I want to format it to two decimal places, I would do this:

```
{{"%.2f" | format(my_dollar_var)}}
```

But what if my_dollar_var is None?  In that case, I'd like to show something else (like a question mark or a dash -- but not a zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a customer Currency filter:

```
 def Currency(value):
     if(value == None):
          return "???"
     else:
          return "${:,.2f}".format(float(value))

jinja2.filters.FILTERS['Currency'] = Currency
```

Then just use:

```
{{ PRICE | Currency }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what file does the definition and registration of the filter go in?

Comment: This article should help you.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-python/YNCUxuGzmwc/i8tSUNB3bjUJ

Comment: oh, it appears that the registration method is dependent on which adapter you are using to integrate Django and Jinja2 (coffin, django_jinga, etc).  I'm using django_jinja, and the answer is at https://django-jinja.readthedocs.org/en/latest/differences.html (search for "Register Global Functions")